# retriving data in coldfusion and putting it to textboxes

Tags: mysql, coldfusion-8

can anyone suggest a simple code to retrieve data from a table in MSQL5 and add it to particular text boxes in coldfusion?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to be more specific than that to get any decent help. It basically goes like this though:

```
<cfquery name="myRecordset" datasource="myDataSource">
SELECT MyField FROM MyTable
</cfquery>
```

That gets your recordset. Now output the field somewhere:

```
<cfoutput>#myRecordset.myField#</cfoutput>
```

Or put it into a text field:

```
<cfoutput><input type="text" name="myInput" value="#myRecordset.myField#" /></cfoutput>
```

Or if you're using `<cfform>` you can do this:

```
<cfinput type="text" name="myInput" value="#myRecordset.myField#" />
```

Hopefully that gets you what you need, otherwise please be more specific with your question.